# how to screen share using python vidstream onto a django html page?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the python window to show on the django html page but im not sure how to as im new to django. I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xy4JKvqsV4 to set up the python script for screen sharing

Im running the receiver.py on the linux machine and the sender.py on the windows virtual machine.

When both receiver.py and sender.py is being runned, the screen of the sender will show as a new tab but i want to be able to show this screen on the django html page.

So how do i get the screen capture to show on the django web server?

receiver.py

```
from vidstream import StreamingServer
import threading

receiver = StreamingServer('ipaddr', 8080)

t = threading.Thread(target=receiver.start_server)
t.start()

while input("") != 'STOP':
    continue

receiver.stop_server()
```

sender.py

```
from vidstream import ScreenShareClient
import threading

sender = ScreenShareClient('ipaddr', 8080)

t = threading.Thread(target=sender.start_stream)
t.start()

while input("") != 'STOP':
    continue

sender.stop_stream()
```

Comment: You need to be more precise.  This does NOT show the screen of the sender as a "new tab".  It shows it as a separate application window.  This is a standalone GUI application.  To route this through a Django server into a web browser, you would have to modify the `vidstream` code to read the video stream into local bitmaps, then send those bitmaps to the browser.  It's not an easy task.

Comment: Basically i want to be able to stream the desktop video of a windows virtual machine to a linux django web server but with vidstream im only able to get the separate application window and im not sure how to get that window to show onto a django web server. It doesnt have to use vidstream but since that is the one im able to get working to screen share the windows vm to my linux machine.